# Can I integrate my app onto instagram and publish in the app store?

Tags: ios

I'm currently working on an app that allows some feature to be displayed when a user clicks on another instagram user's pictures, ie, when the picture and the provision to comment on the comment section displays. This is a simple feature that in a way overlays over this page. M question is, does instagram or any other photo sharing app allow this?

Once the user downloads my app, he/she will be allowed to integrate my app with instagram and have this feature enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question right or not. But there is no way to `overlay` your view to other application. There is a way to display part of your application in other application, which called `extension` but Instagram needs to design their application to add that feature which likely impossible.

Other way you can think of is checking if Instagram has API to see if a photo is liked/commented then you can response to that action.